# Programically adding child controls to a asp.net composite control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, custom-server-controls

Not found anything that directly answers my problem, so hopefully someone can shed some light on it.

I have two Composite Controls, lets call them BudgetTable and BudgetTableItem, where BudgetTable contains a list of BudgetTableItem.

So far everything works so long as I add new RowItems in the HTML View - when I add one programmatically it appears, but doesn't survive postback.

I can only assume I'm doing something boneheaded with ViewState, and would appreciate any pointers!

Thanks in advance.

The HTML:

```
    <hea:BudgetTable runat="server" ID="btTest" MaximumFundingAvailable="7000" CssClass="bob">
            <Items>
                    <hea:BudgetTableItem runat="server" Description="Test1" />
                    <hea:BudgetTableItem runat="server" Description="Test2" />
                    <hea:BudgetTableItem runat="server" Description="Test3" />
            </Items>        
    </hea:BudgetTable>
```

The code behind:

```
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
[ParseChildren(true)]
public class BudgetTableItem : CompositeControl {

    private TextBox _description = new TextBox();

    private TextBox _cost = new TextBox();

    private CheckBox _heaFunded = new CheckBox();

    /*public delegate void AddRow();
    public delegate void RemoveRow(BudgetTableItem item);

    public event AddRow AddNewRow;
    public event RemoveRow RemoveNewRow;*/

    public string ItemName {
        get {
            var viewstate = ViewState["ItemName"];
            return (viewstate is string) ? (string)viewstate : "default";
        }
        set {
            ViewState["ItemName"] = value;
        }
    }

    public bool ShowRemoveRow {
        get {
            var viewstate = ViewState["ShowRemoveRow"];
            return (viewstate != null && viewstate is bool) ? (bool)viewstate : false;
        }
        set {
            ViewState["ShowRemoveRow"] = value;
        }
    }

    public bool ShowAddRow {
        get {
            var viewstate = ViewState["ShowAddRow"];
            return (viewstate != null && viewstate is bool) ? (bool)viewstate : false;
        }
        set {
            ViewState["ShowAddRow"] = value;
        }
    }

    public string Description {
        get {
            return _description.Text;
        }
        set {
            _description.Text = value;
        }
    }

    public decimal Cost {
        get {
            decimal cost =0;
            decimal.TryParse(_cost.Text, out cost);
            return cost;
        }
        set {
            _cost.Text = value.ToString();
        }
    }

    public bool HeaFunded {
        get {
            return _heaFunded.Checked;
        }
        set {
            _heaFunded.Checked = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls() {

        Controls.Clear();

        HtmlTableCell tableCell1 = new HtmlTableCell();
        HtmlTableCell tableCell2 = new HtmlTableCell();
        HtmlTableCell tableCell3 = new HtmlTableCell();
        HtmlTableCell tableCell4 = new HtmlTableCell();

        tableCell1.Attributes.Add("class", "col1");
        tableCell2.Attributes.Add("class", "col2");
        tableCell3.Attributes.Add("class", "col3");
        tableCell4.Attributes.Add("class", "col4");

        tableCell1.Controls.Add(_description);
        tableCell2.Controls.Add(_cost);
        tableCell3.Controls.Add(_heaFunded);

        /*if (ShowAddRow || ShowRemoveRow) {

            Button addNewButton = new Button();

            addNewButton.Text = (ShowAddRow) ? "Add Row" : "Remove";

            if (ShowAddRow) {                   
                addNewButton.Click += new EventHandler(addNewButton_Click);
            }

            if (ShowRemoveRow) {
                addNewButton.Click += new EventHandler(removeButton_Click);
            }

            tableCell4.Controls.Add(addNewButton);
        }
        else{*/
            tableCell4.InnerHtml = "&nbsp;";
        //}

        Controls.Add(tableCell1);
        Controls.Add(tableCell2);
        Controls.Add(tableCell3);
        Controls.Add(tableCell4);
    }

    /*void addNewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (AddNewRow != null) {
            AddNewRow();
        }
    }*/

    /*void removeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (RemoveNewRow != null) {
            RemoveNewRow(this);
        }
    }*/

    protected override void RecreateChildControls() {
        EnsureChildControls();
    }

    public override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer) {
        writer.Write("<tr>");
    }

    public override void RenderEndTag(HtmlTextWriter writer) {
        writer.Write("</tr>");
    }

}
```

Comment: Make sure you are always adding the same children on each and every postback, and preferably as part of the `Init` stage

Comment: Agreed with freefaller. The issue is in the code-behind of your page where you are instantiating the control, not in the code for the control itself.  As a stateless environment, controls don't exist between postbacks without being explicitly created (which is part of what the aspx is doing). If you add your control from the code-behind of the page, it needs to be recreated for each postback.

Comment: If i understand the problem correctly, I think you need to concentrate on figuring out what goes on with the BudgetTable control. IT should make sure that all child controls are persisted and restored on post back.

Answer (score 0):

Controls, custom or otherwise that require a `ViewState` and wish to receive events should be created in `Init`.

Http is stateless. Your entire page with all its controls is recreated on every postback. Controls that you add in the design view, are added to your designer.cs file, and created for you. When you add controls yourself, you must write code to recreate the controls on every PostBack that occurs later.

You can use the session to remember which controls were added by code and add them on later PostBacks.